# как настроить nginx и разрешить только определенные файлы

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, settings, location

Как в location прописать, что бы можно было только `php, html, js, css, jpg, jpeg, gif, png, ico`, а все остальное запретить под 404? Даже файлы без расширения. Писал точечный запрет на некоторые файлы по расширению, но хотелось бы просто разрешить нужное, а остальное запретить.

Comment: Посмотрите [доклад](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jf3wIN-FwW4) разработчика nginx (он крайне не рекомендует делать так как Вам хочется), лучше по одному, так быстрей работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    server_name media.site.ru;
    listen      80;

    location / {
        root /var/www/storage/f2;

        deny all; # deny by default

        location ~ "\.(php|html|js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$" {
            allow all;
        }
    }
}
```

В директиву `server_name` запишите имя вашего сайта.

В директиву `root` запишите абсолютный путь к директории с файлами (без закрывающего слеша).

---

```
$ curl --head http://media.site.ru/q.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.0

$ curl --head http://media.site.ru/priglos.zip
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.19.0
```

Comment: Читайте комментарий выше, может и Вам пригодиться...

Comment: @noname2019 я знаю, просто отвечаю на вопрос )

Comment: не работает, пробовал еще менять. он либо все блокирует либо все разрешает

Comment: @AlgiZ попробуй снова

Comment: @nörbörnën при такой конфигурации php файлы он скачивает вместо отображения + приходится теперь к урлу добавлять index.php

Comment: @AlgiZ ну в чём проблема, убери php из списка и поставь проксирование php-запросов на бэк.

Comment: @nörbörnën я плохо разбираюсь в nginx, неужели сделать определенные типы файлов доступными, а другие нет так сложно?
я просто хотел чтобы все кроме этих выдавало 403 или 404

Comment: @AlgiZ я сделал, конфиг в ответе